# How to determine which line specific line of a file being read

Tags: java, file, line

```
Scanner scans = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter filename: ");
  String thisfile = scans.nextLine();
  File thatfile = new File(thisfile);
  FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(thatfile);
  int i;
  while ((i = fileInput.read()) != -1) {
     char a = (char) i;
   }
```

I'm using the code above to get a file(a java program) and search the file by each character. How can I determine which line a certain character is in. For example if this was the program:

```
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World");
}
}
```

If I was on the S of System, how would I be able to correctly determine that it is in line 3, using code? Sorry if I'm not clear but it's hard to explain.

Comment: Consider a bufferedReader? It has a `readLine()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about enhancing you loop like so

```
char newline_character = <whatever is appropriate for your file>;
int line = 0;
while ((i = fileInput.read()) != -1) {
   char a = (char) i;
   if (a==newline_character) { ++line; }
}
```

Comment: Oops, I was in C mode. Fixed it.

Comment: What should I put between the <>